# How do you efficiently group by multiple columns in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

With dplyr you can group by columns like this:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5), b=c(2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5))
df %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  summarise(count = n())
```

If I want to group by two columns all the guides say:

```
df %>%
  group_by(a,b) %>%
  summarise(count = n())
```

But can I not feed the `group_by()` parameters more efficiently somehow, rather than having to type them in explicitly, e.g. like:

```
cols = colnames(df)
df %>%
  group_by(cols) %>%
  summarise(count = n())
```

I have examples where I want to group by 10+ columns, and it is pretty horrible to write it out if you can just parse their names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`across` and curly-curly is the answer (even though it doesn't make sense to `group_by` using all your columns)

```
cols = colnames(df)
df %>%
  group_by(across({{cols}}) %>%
  summarise(count = n())
```

Comment: Cool, I will check it out. I have updated the question to make it more clear :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `across` with any of the tidy selectors. For example if you want all columns

```
df %>%
  group_by(across(everything())) %>%
  summarise(count = n())
```

Of if you want a list

```
cols <- c("a","b")
df %>%
  group_by(across(all_of(cols))) %>%
  summarise(count = n())
```

See `help("language", package="tidyselect")` for all the selection options.